# CKEditor removeAllListener breaks decrease indent functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, ckeditor

I am using ckeditor version 4x for my application. I am facing strange issue with decrease indent functionality when using below code to increase performance before generating editor in internet explorer.

```
 CKEDITOR.removeAllListeners(); // this breaks decrease indent 
 CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
        extraPlugins: indent,indentblock
    });
```

After commenting removeAllListeners function, Decrease indent working as expected but again performance issue raise and throws ' long running script error' in internet explorer.

When we use removeAllListeners() function, long running error gone and decrease indent not working after increase indent. We have to manually press **backspace** to enable decrease indent icon.

[image]

From above screen, red highlighted box shows decrease indent is still not enable after increase indent the text.This is because of using removeAllListeners() function before generating editor. Green box show it is works fine after removing it but long running error comes which results page frozen.

Please advise.

Comment: I could reproduce the issue with IE and Chrome browser, so I suppose the issue is related to the ckeditor plugin, I suggest you could post your question to [ckeditor-dev forum](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/issues).

Comment: @Dillion I have posted https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/issues/2494. Thanks